# Как лучше хранить данные?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, архитектура, хранение-данных

подскажите, пожалуйста, какое решение будет лучше для хранения данны.
Для  пользователя нужно хранить информацию, представляет она из себя пару ключ - значение,  нужно будет оформлять поиск по пользователю и этому ключу. В среднем 200 - 5000 таких пар, в очень редких случаях может быть пару десятков тысяч. Количество пользователей не больше 120.
На сервере стоит MySQL.

В плане оптимизации будет ли нормально функционировать таблица связанная с пользователем и хранящая ключ(с индексом) и значение?

Нужно все это для того, чтобы лишний раз не подтягивать с внешних API большой объем данных.
То есть обновляться это таблица для отдельного пользователя будет достаточно редко.
Существуют ли какие-то важные настройки для оптимизации БД в этой ситуации, сколько это будет примерно весить(такая таблица на 400к), и нормальное вообще ли такое решение?

Comment: 5к пар на 120 юзеров - это меньше миллиона записей. Вообще ни о чём. А если ключ и значение - не многомегабайтные тексты, так и вовсе несерьёзная нагрузка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит как типовая нагрузка, которая будет нормально себя чувствовать на типовых настройках, при условии что сервер - не бабушкина швейная машинка.

Лучшее, что вы в данный момент можете сделать - это собрать тестовые данные и проверить, насколько шустро все работает, а потом делать выводы и *оптимизировать*

Индексы расставить не забудте :)